# jQuery to add a class to image links without messing up when the link passes variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK so I was using a bit of jquery to select all the `<a>` tags on the page and if they link to an image file to add a `zoom` class to it for the purposes of a lightbox.
This is the code which works

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"], a[href*=".jpg"]').addClass('zoom');
});
```

There is a problem with this though;

Say I have a link which just goes to another page but passes an image url as a GET variable in the URL the lightbox is activated as a result of this and fails because the link is not actually to an image. For example:

```
<a href="http://example.com/a-normal-page/?pic=http://example.com/pics/picture.jpg">Link text</a>
```

In the above instance the jQuery script will add the zoom class to this anchor even though it doesn't actually link to a picture.
This wouldn't usually be an issue as you would leave the page to go to the link's destination before the lightbox has a chance to appear, but in times where a new tab/window is opened I get a failed lightbox coming up.

This is particularly prevalent on social media buttons such as Pinterest which passes an image url within the link.

[apologies for the title - I wasn't sure how best to phrase it. Please feel free to edit to something more suitable]

Comment: can you setup a fiddle for it?

Comment: I attempted to do so but my particular problem uses quite a few external scripts which makes JSFiddle quite a mess and fancybox doesn't seem to work on it. Problem solved anyhoo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add the `zoom` class only if `href` attribute doesn't contain a `?` (or, in other words, a querystring is not included), e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"], a[href*=".jpg"]').each(function() {
        if (this.href.indexOf('?') < 0) {
             $(this).addClass('zoom');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the href with a simple regex to check that the image is not in the query string, and filter out the false positives.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $imgLinks = $('a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".jpg"]');
    $imgLinks.filter(function() {
        return !$(this)
                .attr('href')
                .match(/^http\:\/\/.*\?.*http\:\/\/.*\.(png|gif|jpg)$/);
    })
    .addClass('zoom');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am sure your answer would work well but I have opted for Fabrizio's method